# Missing space with DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: spacing, delimiters, mathtools

I’m trying to define an `abs` command for absolute values using `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the `mathtools` package, but I’m running into some spacing issues.

I’d normall write `\sup_n \abs{a_n}` defined by `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}`.
But then there is some space missing.

[image: Actual output.]

I would instead expect the following output, which I get using `\sup_n |a_n|`.

[image: Expected output]

With `\sup_n {\abs{a_n}}` this issue does not appear, but I find this additional pair of curly braces too cumbersome.
I also tried some variations, but both versions of `\abs` seem to have the same issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\altabs}{|}{|}

\begin{document}
\[
  \sup_n |a_n|              \quad % expected output
  \sup_n \abs{a_n}          \quad
  \sup_n {\abs{a_n}}        \quad % expected output
  \sup_n \lvert a_n \rvert  \quad
  \sup_n \altabs{a_n}       \quad
  \sup_n {\altabs{a_n}}           % expected output
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Complete output]

Where is this problem coming from, and how can I get `DeclarePairedDelimiter` to give the right spacing?

Comment: The fact is that the space should *not* be there: if you use the proper `\sup_n\lvert a_n\rvert`, you see it. Just like `\sup(a_1,\dots,a_n)` should not have space.

Comment: In addition to egregs comment, remember that `|...|` is not the correct syntax for absolute value. `|` is a normal symbol (an ord), whereas `\lvert` and `\rvert` are `|` with type math open and math close respectfully (just as `()`). When `\sub` sees an ord like a letter or `|` it inserts a space, whereas it does not insert a space when it sees something of type math open. Internally `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` will always make the fences into open and close types which is why your `\abs` and `\altabs` gives the same result.

Comment: I guess then that my latex code does not properly reflect what I actually want to express:
I understand something like “sup(f)” as “sup( ) applied to f”, but “sup |f|” as “sup (written without paratheses) applied |f|”, *not* as “sup| | applied to f”.
Hence I expect the same spacing for both “sup f” and “sup |f|”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be no space between the operator name and a delimiter, so the output one gets from

```
\sup_{n}\lvert a_{n}\rvert
```

is right (and is one of the reasons why `amsmath` introduced `\lvert` and `\rvert` to begin with).

On the other hand, you may like the thin space when the delimiter is a vertical bar. Easy enough: add a dummy `\mathop{}` before it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\absinner}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\altabsinner}{|}{|}

\newcommand{\abs}{\mathop{}\absinner}
\newcommand{\altabs}{\mathop{}\altabsinner}

\begin{document}
\[
  \sup_n |a_n|              \quad % expected output
  \sup_n \abs{a_n}          \quad
  \sup_n {\abs{a_n}}        \quad % expected output
  \sup_n \altabs{a_n}       \quad
  \sup_n {\altabs{a_n}}           % expected output
\]

\begin{alignat*}{3}
a_n - \abs{a_n} &\quad& a_n-\lvert a_n\rvert &\quad& a_n-|a_n|\\
 -\abs{a_n} && -\abs{a_n} && -|a_n|
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd not do it myself, though.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose an `\mathop{}` instead of just `{}`?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Try and see the differences in the examples.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution but used `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` to place the dummy `\mathop{}`.